# Probability Conditional Question Please Help

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, decision-trees

I have a probability question which I would appreciate some help with.

[image]

a) Complete the values in the tree diagram

b) The probability that Terry will not be the champion is 0.58. Find the value of p

c) Given that Terry did not become the champion, find the probability she lost in the semi-final

My main struggle is with c as I understand it is a conditional probability question but personally I think the events are independent and thus P(A|B) = P(A) therefore 0.3 but the alternative is to say 15/29 by saying P(A and B) / P(B) = 0.3/0.58 = 15/29.

Any helpt would be greatly appreciated as to which working is correct. Thanks!!

Comment: you can read about [Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem). If it's already defined that she lost the final, you shouldn't take account of chance that she would win it.

Comment: @DavidK sorry my old comment was wrong, it should be "If it's already defined that Terry did not become the champion...". My opinion is: at the beginning, $$\mathcal P(Terry.loses.semi-final) + P(Terry.loses.final) + P(Terry.wins.final) = 1$$. But if we know that she already did not become the champion, then $$\mathcal P(Terry.wins.final) = 0$$. So the OP should not take account of chance that she would win it

Comment: @AcaNg Just in case we're merely talking past each other: Do you agree that the correct answer is $15/29,$ or do you think it is $3/10$?

Comment: @DavidK yes as you say I mean $$P(Terry.wins.final∣(Terry.wins.final)^C)=0$$. And I got the same result 15/29 too :)

Comment: Based on the chat @AcaNg and I actually agree on the answer and on a suitable method to find it. I just misunderstood the comments. The trick is in what you do after you "ignore" the "Terry wins final" event. The probability of each remaining event has to be increased while maintaining the ratio between the probabilities ... which means that the "Terry loses semifinal" event will end up with a (conditional) probability greater than $0.3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definition of $\mathcal P(A \mid B),$
$$\mathcal P(A \cap B) = \mathcal P(A \mid B) \mathcal P(B).$$
Any intuition that leads you to a different conclusion is a mistaken intuition about conditional probabilities.

Dependence of one event on another in probability **may** arise because the other event has a causal effect on the first one, but that is not what defines dependence.
Dependence also is a two-way street: it happens when
$$  \mathcal P(A \cap B) \neq  \mathcal P(A)  \mathcal P(B),$$
and as you might guess from the symmetry of this formula, if $B$ is dependent on $A$ then $A$ is dependent on $B.$

If you want to think of this in more causal terms, consider
$\mathcal P(A \mid B) : (1 - \mathcal P(A \mid B))$
as the fair odds on a bet that $A$ will occur, with the condition that the bet is settled with these odds if $B$ occurs, but if $B$ does not occur the bet is canceled.

Suppose a friend says to you, "I bet you Terry will lose the semi-final. If she wins I pay you a dollar, if she loses you pay me two dollars." This is a favorable bet for you (and a bad bet for your friend) because the expected winnings of $1$ dollar with $0.7$ probability outweighs than the expected loss of $2$ dollars with $0.3$ probability.

But suppose your friend puts an extra condition on the bet--you have to wait until after the final before settling the bet, and if Terry wins the final the whole bet is canceled. You now have a much lower chance of winning, but just as big a chance of losing. In fact, is now a bad bet for you and a favorable bet for your friend. You should ask for better odds on the bet.
This corresponds to the fact that $\mathcal P(A \mid B) > \mathcal P(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

B) The probability that Terry will not be the champion is
$$(1-p)+0.4p=1-0.6p$$
Solving,
\begin{align*}
    1-0.6p=0.58 \\
    p=0.7
\end{align*}

C) The answer is
$$\frac{1-p}{1-0.6p}=\frac{0.3}{0.58}=\frac{15}{29}$$
The events are not independent, since the event "Terry loses in the semi-final" is a subset of the event "Terry did not become the champion." Knowing the former, you also know that the latter occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just don't get how they are not independent? because her loosing the champaionship comes after the semi final so how can you explain them being dependent? Also, she could win the semi final and lose the final and still not be the champion.